# Android Studio and Ryzen CPU?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, cpu, amd-processor

**I know it could be marked as duplicate. But none of the threads helped me, so I decided to make my own.**

I'm a *Java back-end developer* and I've decided to learn some Android stuff.
I worked on Android Studio several years ago having `i5-4570` processor. Then I gave up. Now I see Android Studio is really really interesting, so I have downloaded it.

Now I have `Ryzen 5 1600` processor. It's really great... but...

None of the Android emulators work for me.

**What have I tried?**

- Android Studio built-in emulator. (Doesn't support **AMD-V**)
- Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator (Crashes *Windows 10* and bootloops motherboard till a hard-reset...)
- *Genymotion* (personal use) emulator (Throws a ***BSOD*** with error *SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION*)

I don't have any idea what to do now, I don't want to use USB debugging solution because it's... weird and probably slow, because my phone is really old.

Any suggestions? I'm really starting to give up with android development by now.

Comment: Android emulator works just fine on Linux+AMD. Try some FOSS stuff such as Debian or Arch :) https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processor you've mentioned is a new one. Maybe there aren't any emulators which can run with your processor. Since you haven't included Bluestacks, you may want to try it once.

Also Using a real Android phone is actually faster than using an emulator because while running an emulator the CPU is shared between Android Studio and the emulator which makes build process slower.

And if you feel weird because of the phone which is wired with a cable, you can use wireless debugging. Just search for it in Google or the play store.

Comment: I've tried NoxPlayer (works with AMD-V) and it's super-fast, but it's bad for development because it doesn't have any Android Studio integrations. (I think?)

Comment: I did wireless debugging using Android Studio plugin (ADB Wifi) and `adb` commands. It works like a charm, 12 seconds to compile and deploy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use Bluestack 3 or N (Beta). Works with AMD V hypervisor. Make sure your BIOS had enabled the SVM virtualisation settings. Start Android Studios after the Bluestack program is runnning. The android studios should detect the emulator and display the console messages when you finally start Android Studios. Works great on my AMD Ryzen 1600 now.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try it.

Comment: Update: debugging mode seems to be disabled (mo eay to attached a debugger) on Bluestack, so can only install the apk to the emulator. Nonetheless, still allow "debugging" with good old Log.d

Comment: Update: Read about my full experience on finally able to code Android apps with hardware emulator support in Windows 10 -> https://medium.com/@mipsmonsta/amd-ryzen-and-quest-to-run-android-emulator-in-hardware-mode-37c514f1a59b

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion should work.

VirtualBox (the software behind Genymotion) still has some conflict problems when Hyper-V is enabled in Windows. Try to open the Genymotion emulator image in VirtualBox and under its Settings -> System -> Acceleration, try changing the Paravirtualization Interface and see if that helps.

If that doesn't work, Disable Hyper-V under Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Hyper-V and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

currently using Ryzen 1600 with ubuntu 17.10 on b350 motherboard
works like charm!!!

Also tested on Windows; butter smooth performance with the new drivers by Google

---

All Ryzen CPUs are compatible now for Linux as well as windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please try new AndroidStudio 3.1.3 with windows 10
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=547DXRq8zAo

Answer (score -1):

I asked Gennymotion n they said it should. 
 u need to enable amd-v in bios?