# What is the status of Android Studio 3.5 running on Win10 with Ryzen 5 (or 7) CPU?

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

Really trying to not create a duplicate.
I've read the closest SO on this and it is quite old: 
[Android Studio and Ryzen CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743241/android-studio-and-ryzen-cpu)

It's time to upgrade my hardware since my i7, 8GB RAM laptop can no longer run Android Studio and the emulator at the same time (major memory issues). Unfortunately, my laptop can only go to 8GB.

I am definitely considering a Ryzen 5 or 7 since I can save so much $$$ (compared to similar Intel choices).

On Ryzen, can I run the normal HAXM emulator?  The one I'm used to running on my i7?  Or do I have to run something different?

Does anyone have comparison stats?  My i7 starts the emulator just about instantly on my i7.  But I can no longer run the emulator and android Studio (AS) at the same time (due to RAM being eaten up by AS and associated Java runtimes).

Is running on the Ryzen not solid?  Am I going to see a lot of crashes?  Is it going to be so slow it drives me crazy?  If not I'd rather pay the extra for the Intel chip?
Hope someone out there is an Android dev and has experience to share.

**Win10 Version?**

Also, I just read the requirements for Hyper-V. I'm running Windows Home edition. Do I need Windows Pro or Enterprise to run with Ryzen 5/7? Will I be required to use Hyper-V?

The following is from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

> ```
> Windows 10 Enterprise, Pro, or Education
> 64-bit Processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
> CPU support for VM Monitor Mode Extension (VT-c on Intel CPUs).
> Minimum of 4 GB memory.
> ```
>
> **The Hyper-V role cannot be installed on Windows 10 Home.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following information from July 09, 2018 (a while ago and AS 3.2 was out) that seems to indicate that :
 1. Android emulator is supported and will run with AMD Ryzen chips
 2. You will need to turn on Windows HyperVisor Platform (which should be available via Windows 10 Home)

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

It also states (my emphasis shown where I am confused -- not sure what Hyper-V running at same time gives me) :

> **If you want to use Hyper-V at the same time as the Android Emulator**
>   on your Intel processor-based computer, you will also need the same
>   Android Studio and Android Emulator versions as listed above, but with
>   the additional requirements:
>
> Enable via Windows Features: "Hyper-V" - Only available for Windows 10 Professional/Education/Enterprise
>       Intel Processor : Intel® Core™ processor that supports Virtualization Technology (VT-x), Extended Page Tables (EPT), and
>
> Unrestricted Guest (UG) features. Additionally VT-x needs to be
>   enabled in the BIOS.

**More Info - Definitive Answer**

My son has a machine with Gigabyte m/b and a [Ryzen 5 2600x](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-2600x) and we installed Android Studio 3.5 and made the appropriate changes tonight.

- The board / CPU supports SVM (virtualization technology) so we made
  that change in the BIOS.
- Next we turned on the Win10 setting for Windows HyperVisor Platform.

We downloaded an x86 Oreo image via Android Studio / AVD Manager and ran it and it runs very fast and smoothly on that machine (16GB RAM).

We didn't see any problems.  Loaded up a basic template app and deployed it to the Android VM and it ran great. It all looks good to me.  Support for Ryzen seems to be just fine.  I will be buying a board and Ryzen just like his.

**Update - 2020-03-23**

I did purchase the Gigabyte mainboard and the Ryzen 5 2600x and I've been running it for over 6 months now and running current versions of Android Studio (keeping it updated) during that time.
I have 16GB RAM and the CPU can run Android Studio and at least two emulators running at the same time with no problems at all.

**Ubuntu Linux / Windows 10 Home Edition Dual Boot**

I dual boot my machine running Ubuntu and Win10.  I run Ubuntu 90% of the time because Android Studio runs so smoothly on it, but I also boot in to Win10 and Android Studio runs fine there too.  (Home edition works fine.)
This confirms that the AMD processors work completely fine running the Android emulators.

Comment: hello !  i have AMD ryzen 5 2600x too and RAM 16 G as well but. somehow android studio on my pc run really slow since first time i installed it. do you have any trick for this issue ? and please note that im newbie.

Comment: @cheasotheara Unfortunately I do not have a trick for that.  I run Android Studio under Ubuntu Linux 95% of the time and it is blazing fast.  I have found that Win10 itself runs a lot of overhead processes and seems to be far slower on the same hardware.   My machine is dual boot (Win10 and Ubuntu) but since it runs so much better on Ubuntu, I run on Linux about 99% of the time.  Have you tried re-installing Android Studio to see if it gets better?  Also, if you have the space, try dual boot with Ubuntu.  Also, does machine have an SSD? If you have HDD, emulator is run off drive can be slow.